# Compare and get Xml Differences

Tags: xml, vb.net, git

guys i have this code for Get XML Diff from two XML when somenthing in the XML Change
my question is how i can configure the output to show the node name of the change?

for example i get this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="14065382161691288455" options="IgnoreChildOrder         IgnoreNamespaces IgnorePrefixes " fragments="no"       xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
   <xd:node match="1">
   <xd:node match="2">
   <xd:node match="1">
   <xd:change match="1">ADFGFFDFD</xd:change>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:xmldiff>
```

and i want this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="14065382161691288455" options="IgnoreChildOrder         IgnoreNamespaces IgnorePrefixes " fragments="no"       xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
   <xd:node match="1">
   <xd:node match="2">
   <xd:node match="1">
   <xd:change match="1"><NAME>ADFGFFDFDM<NAME></xd:change>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:node>
   </xd:xmldiff>
```

Vb.net code:

```
    Public Function GenDiff(Nodea As String, Nodeb As String, ByRef difDoc As String) As Boolean
    Dim xmldiff As New XmlDiff()
    xmldiff.IgnoreChildOrder = True
    xmldiff.IgnoreNamespaces = True
    xmldiff.IgnorePrefixes = True
    xmldiff.IgnoreComments = False
    xmldiff.IgnorePI = False
    xmldiff.IgnoreWhitespace = False
    xmldiff.Algorithm = XmlDiffAlgorithm.Auto
    Dim StreamW As New StringWriter()
    Dim XmlWriter As New XmlTextWriter(StreamW)
    XmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    Dim Oreader As New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(Nodea))
    Dim Mreader As New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(Nodeb))
    Dim status As Boolean = xmldiff.Compare(Oreader, Mreader, XmlWriter)
    difDoc = StreamW.ToString()
    XmlWriter.Close()
    Oreader.Close()
    Mreader.Close()
    Return status
    End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net apply XSL transformation to XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187782/vb-net-apply-xsl-transformation-to-xml-file)